# GNOME Files - how to add a folder into the left panel (not as a bookmark)

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Want to achieve the following with GNOME Files (formerly called Nautilus) in Ubuntu 22.04:

[image]

In the file *.config/user-dirs.dirs* is already an entry for the desktop (it's called Schreibtisch in German)

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Schreibtisch"
```

That means this config file is useless for what I try to intend, I assume.

So how to add the Desktop shortcut (not via bookmark) to GNOME Files into the left panel?

Comment: This should include a Desktop (or Schreibtisch) item if the directory $HOME/Schreibtisch exists.

Comment: This folder ~/Schreibtisch exists and is valid. Still there is no left panel shortcut in GNOME Files.